# Error message from server side is not displaying in front end

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

When login gets failed in server side `res.status(403).json({ fail: "Login failed" });` message from server side is passing into front end `setHelperText(failMessage);` How can i get the 'Login Failed' message in front end ?

It is displaying error in chrome console >> Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)

`server.js`

```
app.post('/service/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userEmail = req.body.email;
    const userPassword = req.body.password;
    const loginData = await UserModel.findAll({ where: { email: userEmail} });
    const password = loginData[0].password;
    const email = loginData[0].email;
    if(password === userPassword && email === userEmail){
     const privilege  = loginData[0].privilege;
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, privilege, email });
    }else{
      res.status(403).json({ fail: "Login failed" });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
  }
});
```

`Login.js`

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/service/login', { email , password });
    console.log("Front End success message:"+res.data.success);
    if(res.data.success){
      setHelperText("Login successfully");
      setValue(res.data.privilege);
      setError(true);
    }
    else{
      const failMessage = res.data.fail;
      setHelperText(failMessage);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response is not success, (403 in your case), catch block will be executed, so move your logic inside the else block to catch block in the Login.js

```
catch(e) {      
const failMessage = e.response.data.fail;
setHelperText(failMessage);
// console.log(e.data.response); -> to print the server response
}
```

Comment: Is it in server side `catch block` or front end catch block ?

Comment: In the front end

Comment: I am getting an error >>` Line 32:29:  'res' is not defined  no-undef`, because the `res` is not identified in catch (e) {] block..

Comment: In Login.js, replace the console.log line like below

catch (e) {
    console.log(e.response.data);
  }